# Split up NSString using a comma

Tags: json, iphone, split, nsstring

I have a JSON feed connected to my app. One of the items is lat & long separated by a comma. For example: "32.0235, 1.345".

I'm trying to split this up into two separate values by splitting at the comma.

Any advice? Thanks!!

Answer (score 133, accepted):

```
NSArray *strings = [coords componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 17):

```
NSString* myString = @"32.0235, 1.345".
NSArray* myArray = [myString  componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSString* firstString = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* secondString = [myArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

See in [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:)

Answer (score 5):

You want:

`- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator`

using @"," as separator.

Answer (score 2):

This is work for me as I was not looking to define any Array.

```
NSString* firstString = [[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `[yourCommaSeparatedString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]`

that will give a NSArray with strings you can then call floatValue on ;)