# iPhone:How to split NSString in multiple lines and its set into UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split up NSString using a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443535/split-up-nsstring-using-a-comma)

I have an NSString like `Hello,How are you,Norman,Stanley,Fletcher` so I want to split that string when comma separator is occur and that string set into UILabel in iPhone.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Original string:

```
NSString originalString = @"Hello,How are you,Norman,Stanley,Fletcher";
```

Split into multiple lines:

```
NSString multiLineString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:"@\n"];
```

Assign to your label:

```
label.text = mutliLineString;
```

Need to make sure the label takes multiple lines:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Will make it display as many lines as required.

Comment: thanks but i want to set that separated string multiples lines of uilabel

Comment: multiple separate UILabels, or one UILabel containing multiple lines of text?

Comment: thanks but i display spiltted string into uilabel dynamically change label height

Comment: does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel/5660396#5660396

Answer (score 0):

You can use [componentsSeparatedByString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a): method do divide the string. This method will return an array of NSStrings. 
You can display them in to an [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) with [editable](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/editable) property set to no.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like :

```
NSString * str  = @"Hello,How are you,Norman,Stanley,Fletcher";

yourLabel.text = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"\n"]);
```

Comment: thanks but i want to set that separated string multiples lines of uilabel

Answer (score 0):

To split your @"Hello,How are you" use the following code :

```
NSString *string = @"Hello,How are you";
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
```

And to check if there is a comma in a string use this :

```
NSRange matchNotFound;
matchNotFound = [[label text] rangeOfString: @","];
if ((matchNotFound.location != NSNotFound) {
//if there is a comma 
} else {
//if there is no comma 
}
```

Hopping find this useful.