# Separate array into new arrays with similar objects - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an array: Array A which contains the objects

```
"Anchorage, AK"
"Juneau, AK"
"Los Angeles, CA"
"Minneapolis, MS"
"Seatac, WA"
"Seattle, WA"
```

Note: actual array objects do not contain quotation marks.

How can I separate this array into multiple arrays based on the last to characters of the string? It does not matter if the arrays are mutable or not to me.

i.e...

```
Array 2 {
[1] <--- First NSArray
"Anchorage, AK"
"Jeneau, AK"

[2] <--- Second NSArray
"Los Angeles, CA"

[3] <--- Third NSArray
"Minneapolis, MS"

[4] <--- Fourth NSArray
"Seatac, WA"
"Seattle, WA"
}
```

In the real scenario I will not know how many of each state there are. I'm thinking I can do something with the two char length part of the string at the end? Because thats what I want them separated into essentially is states.

Comment: Try to implement something and post the non-working code. We can't just write it for you.

Comment: What are the criteria by which you want to split the array?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I want to group the objects based on the last two characters in the string objects.

Comment: Why do you want an array of arrays? You should have a dictionary where the keys are the states and the values are arrays of cities for the state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay - let me know if this is clear.

```
// Setup the inital array
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Anchorage, AK",
                  @"Juneau, AK",
                  @"Los Angeles, CA",
                  @"Minneapolis, MS",
                  @"Seatac, WA",
                  @"Seattle, WA", nil];

// Create our array of arrays
NSMutableArray *newArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Loop through all of the cities using a for loop
for (NSString *city in array) {
    // Keep track of if we need to creat a new array or not
    bool foundCity = NO;

    // This gets the state, by getting the substring of the last two letters
    NSString *state = [city substringFromIndex:[city length] -2];

    // Now loop though our array of arrays tosee if we already have this state
    for (NSMutableArray *subArray in newArray2) {
        //Only check the first value, since all the values will be the same state
        NSString *arrayCity = (NSString *)subArray[0];
        NSString *arrayState = [arrayCity substringFromIndex:[arrayCity length] -2];

        if ([state isEqualToString:arrayState])
        {
            // Check if the states match... if they do, then add it to this array
            foundCity = YES;
            [subArray addObject:city];

            // No need to continue the for loop, so break stops looking though the arrays.
            break;
        }
    }

    // WE did not find the state in the newArray2, so create a new one
    if (foundCity == NO)
    {
        NSMutableArray *newCityArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:city, nil];
        [newArray2 addObject:newCityArray];
    }


}

//Print the results
NSLog(@"%@", newArray2);
```

My output

```
2014-01-20 20:28:04.787 TemperatureConverter[91245:a0b] (
        (
        "Anchorage, AK",
        "Juneau, AK"
    ),
        (
        "Los Angeles, CA"
    ),
        (
        "Minneapolis, MS"
    ),
        (
        "Seatac, WA",
        "Seattle, WA"
    )
)
```

Comment: But what do I do if I don't know how many of each state there are?

Comment: I don't understand your goal, how exactly do you want to break up the array? What algorithm are you following?  First and last array is 2 and the rest are one?

Comment: I've clarified my question

Comment: Why does Anchorage and Seatac repeat twice?

Comment: Because I had `[subArray addObject:arrayCity];` instead of `[subArray addObject:city];` - fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your help! +1 for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the strings in your original array and [split them by delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6443589/361247) and put them into new array. Then you can look at the arrays and group based on the second element on the array.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to group them based on the second element? I have an array with all the two char state names in the above array.